# WPF bind GradientStopCollection

Tags: wpf, bind

How to bind GradientStopCollection with some GradientStops in ViewModel

```
<Rectangle Width="30" Height="200">
   <Rectangle.Fill>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
          <GradientStopCollection ????? />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GradientBrush` (baseclass of `LinearGradientBrush`) is defined with `[ContentProperty("GradientStops")]`, which means, that the `GradientStopCollection` can be either set directly as content or explicitely as `GradientStops` property.

So you can define a `GradientStopCollection` in resources or code behind and then bind it to your brush.

A little example XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Rectangle Width="30" Height="200" Margin="20">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1"
                                 GradientStops="{Binding}">
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GradientStopCollection c = new GradientStopCollection();
    c.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 0.0));
    c.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Green, 0.5));
    c.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 1.0));
    grid1.DataContext = c;
}
```

I don't think you can manually add/remove individual collection items without code behind, but as said, you should be able to define / replace the whole collection in XAML as well.

**Edit**

So let's suppose you want to decouple your viewmodel a bit more:

```
public class GradientTransferObject
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public double Offset { get; set; }
}

// ....
public ObservableCollection<GradientTransferObject> Gradients { get; set; }
```

Now there is a need to translate the source items into an `GradientStopCollection`. This can be done with something similar to a `CollectionViewSource` - an object that can be hosted as resource, takes an items source and provides an item collection.

```
public class GradientProvider : Freezable
{
    // the resulting items collection
    public GradientStopCollection GradientItems
    {
        get { return (GradientStopCollection)GetValue(GradientItemsProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(GradientItemsPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey GradientItemsPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("GradientItems", typeof(GradientStopCollection), typeof(GradientProvider), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GradientItemsProperty = GradientItemsPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;


    // the items source from viewmodel data
    public IEnumerable<GradientTransferObject> GradientItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<GradientTransferObject>)GetValue(GradientItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GradientItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GradientItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GradientItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable<GradientTransferObject>), typeof(GradientProvider),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourceChanged)));


    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var self = d as GradientProvider;
        if (e.OldValue == e.NewValue)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (e.OldValue is ObservableCollection<GradientTransferObject>)
        {
            var c = e.OldValue as ObservableCollection<GradientTransferObject>;
            c.CollectionChanged -= self.CollectionChanged;
        }
        if (e.NewValue is ObservableCollection<GradientTransferObject>)
        {
            var c = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<GradientTransferObject>;
            c.CollectionChanged += self.CollectionChanged;
        }
        self.UpdateItems();
    }

    private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateItems();
    }

    private void UpdateItems()
    {
        GradientItems = new GradientStopCollection(GradientItemsSource.Select(x => new GradientStop(x.Color, x.Offset)));
    }


    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new GradientProvider();
    }
}
```

The updated xaml example:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:GradientProvider x:Key="gradientSource" GradientItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Rectangle Width="30" Height="200" Margin="20">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1"
                                 GradientStops="{Binding GradientItems,Source={StaticResource gradientSource}}">
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Content="AddGradient" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

The updated code, dynamically changing the gradient collection on button click:

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Gradients = new ObservableCollection<GradientTransferObject>()
    {
        new GradientTransferObject{ Color = Colors.Red, Offset = 0.0},
        new GradientTransferObject{ Color = Colors.Yellow, Offset = 1.0},
    };
    grid1.DataContext = Gradients;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Gradients.Add(new GradientTransferObject { Color = Colors.Green, Offset = 0.5 });
}
```

So as you see, you are free to take it easy with direct usage of `GradientStopCollection` in the viewmodel or go for full abstraction where your viewmodel source and your view work on completely different data types.